# QComboBox nested within a Qmenu?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, toolbar, combo-box

Is it possible to nest a `QComboBox` inside of a `Qmenu` within QGIS?

Below is my current code and an associated screenshot with the unexpected results.

(orange = current incorrect placement, green = ideal placement)

```
# CSV attribute editor toolbox layer population(s)
self.projCombo = QComboBox(self.iface.mainWindow())
self.projCombo.addItem('example slot')
self.projCombo.addItem('another example slot')
self.projCombo.addItem('the last example slot')
self.ShapeLayerList = QWidgetAction(self.projCombo)

# build the sub-menus for CSV attribute editor
self.popupMenu2A = QMenu( self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.popupMenu2A.setTitle("Shape Data")
self.popupMenu2A.addAction(self.ShapeLayerList)
self.toolButton2A = QToolButton()
self.toolButton2A.setMenu( self.popupMenu2A )
self.toolButton2A.setDefaultAction( self.editAttribStress )
self.toolButton2A.setPopupMode( QToolButton.InstantPopup )

self.popupMenu2B = QMenu( self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.toolButton2B = QToolButton()
self.toolButton2B.setMenu( self.popupMenu2B )
self.toolButton2B.setDefaultAction( self.editAttribProp)
self.toolButton2B.setPopupMode( QToolButton.InstantPopup )
self.popupMenu2B.setTitle("Grid Data")
self.popupMenu2B.addAction( self.editAttribProp )

# build the main CSV attribute editor dropdown toolbutton
self.popupMenu2 = QMenu( self.iface.mainWindow() )
self.toolButton2 = QToolButton()
self.toolButton2.setMenu( self.popupMenu2 )
self.toolButton2.setDefaultAction( self.editAttributes )
self.toolButton2.setPopupMode( QToolButton.InstantPopup )
self.popupMenu2.addMenu(self.popupMenu2A)
self.popupMenu2.addMenu(self.popupMenu2B)
```

[image: combobox location?]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is with

```
self.ShapeLayerList = QWidgetAction(self.projCombo)
```

That is creating a QWidgetAction with the combo box as its parent widget, not its child widget. Try:

```
self.ShapeLayerList=QWidgetAction(None)
self.ShapeLayerList.setDefaultWidget(self.projCombo)
```

Comment: Error return:  'TypeError: QWidgetAction(QObject): not enough arguments' .  Although your parent-child notion makes sense...

Comment: Oops - sorry. That should have been QWidgetAction(None) instead. I've edited to reflect this.

Comment: No worries. Is the manner of adding an 'empty' QObject rather then a 'None Type' also reasonable (and pythonic)?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to ndawson for his advice; direction in the right direction:

Had to implement a test QObject to fufill the parent-child relations...

```
        # CSV attribute editor toolbox layer population(s)
    self.projCombo = QComboBox(self.iface.mainWindow())
    self.projCombo.addItem('example slot')
    self.projCombo.addItem('another example slot')
    self.projCombo.addItem('the last example slot')
    !!! > self.objectTest = QObject()
    !!! > self.ShapeLayerList = QWidgetAction(self.objectTest)
    self.ShapeLayerList.setDefaultWidget(self.projCombo)

    # build the sub-menus for CSV attribute editor
    self.popupMenu2A = QMenu( self.iface.mainWindow() )
    self.popupMenu2A.setTitle("Shape Data")
    self.popupMenu2A.addAction(self.ShapeLayerList)
```

[image]